# Google places api is making so many requests even using session token

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-places-api, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

I am working on a project and it makes some requests to Google Place API services. I'm seeing a lot of requests in my cloud panel even though I've made 3 requests to the API. Today I made a few requests (maybe max 10) and I saw 80+ requests on my google cloud panel, and it is effect to my billing.

My project is basically;

- API Request 1- find a place with Autocomplete (with session token)
- API Request 2- get place details with place_id (with session token)
- API Request 3- get one photo with photo_referance

As a result, according to my calculations, there should be 3 requests. Why google is seeing so many requests ?